# Blazor.NET: What causes "A task was canceled" within JavaScript

Tags: blazor

I've got a **Server Side Blazor.NET application** (dotnet core 3.1) with library:
**ProtectedBrowserStorage** (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ProtectedBrowserStorage) for encrypted storage in Client Browswer

Sometimes there are errors in my log files that looks like:

```
2020-04-01 14:05:17.4809 Error System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeWithDefaultCancellation[T](String identifier, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ProtectedBrowserStorage.ProtectedBrowserStorage.GetAsync[T](String purpose, String key)
   at PegasusV6.LocalStorageService.LoadBasket(MenuDTO menu) in LocalStorageService.cs:line 40 A task was canceled.
```

My problem is that I don't know what causes this error in JavaScript calls.

Is there maybe a Server restriction that can fix this kind of error?

Or is it client side that user maybe has not good internet speed / connection which is highly required for server side Blazor?

Hope someone can give me a hint or anything what could improve it. 
This is the C# function that is called:

```
    public async Task LoadBasket(MenuDTO menu)
    {
        try
        {
            AppState.BasketData = await ProtectedLocalStore.GetAsync<BasketState>($"Basket_{My.StoreId}") ?? new BasketState();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            My.Log.Error(ex);
            AppState.BasketData = new BasketState();
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70391074/2440

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a default maximum to the size of an incoming hub message. The first time I encountered this issue I tried to change the *ApplicationMaxBufferSize* and *TransportMaxBufferSize* of the blazor hub but it didn't solve the issue.

Instead add the SignalR service and set the MaximumReceiveMessageSize.

```
        services.AddSignalR(e => {
            e.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 1000;
        });
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still some issues with that kind left... is there any other limitation left that could cause this? Thanks!

2020-06-04 13:56:12.6251 Error System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeWithDefaultCancellation[T](String identifier, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)

Comment: With plain Blazor, instead I fixed this with: `services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddHubOptions(hub => hub.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024); // 100 MB`

Comment: Or with .NET8: `services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents().AddHubOptions(options => { options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 500 * 1024; });`

Answer (score 5):

I got that error sometimes on JsInterop calls to javascript methods without a return value. I learned that it's best to always return a value even if it would not be necessary for the business logic.

That would look something like this in the blazor page:

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("exampleJsMethod");
```

and then in JS:

```
window.exampleJsMethod = () => {
    //do something
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You might try calling your void method with ```await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("exampleJsMethod");``` instead.

See [Call a void JavaScript function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-3.1#call-a-void-javascript-function)

Comment: Yeah I learned that too in the meantime. But I still got the “A task was canceled” error on some occasions e.g. when I call the JS method [open()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

Answer (score 0):

JSRuntime InvokeAsync calls have a default CancellationToken timeout of 45 sec ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.jsinterop.jsruntimeextensions.invokeasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-jsinterop-jsruntimeextensions-invokeasync-1(microsoft-jsinterop-ijsruntime-system-string-system-threading-cancellationtoken-system-object()))).

To remove this timeout just add `CancellationToken.None`

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("JsMethod", System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
```