# JSRuntime.InvokeAsync("open", ...) throws TaskCanceledException

Tags: blazor-server-side

In my blazor-server-side app I am calling JSRuntime.InvokeAsync to open static content in a popup window:

```
await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("open", "/help/help.html", "_blank");
```

It works, but after some time (probably a timeout?) a TaskCanceledException is thrown. I tried calling InvokeVoidAsync, but the effect is the same. I can fix this by catching and ignoring the exception or by removing "await", but I was hoping for a cleaner solution that does not give me complier warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specify cancellationToken as CancellationToken.None

`await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("open", System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, "/help/help.html", "_blank");`

*A cancellation token to signal the cancellation of the operation. Specifying **this parameter will override any default cancellations such as due to timeouts** (DefaultAsyncTimeout) from being applied.*

[Documenation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.jsinterop.jsruntimeextensions.invokevoidasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0#Microsoft_JSInterop_JSRuntimeExtensions_InvokeVoidAsync_Microsoft_JSInterop_IJSRuntime_System_String_System_Threading_CancellationToken_System_Object___)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the compiler error, use discard '_':

```
_ = _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("open", "/help/help.html", "_blank");
```